# Python script to invoke putty application from pycharm IDE

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, pycharm, putty

I have installed Pycharm IDE, and i have putty installed in my pc, how can i invoke putty , login and pass the commands using python script?

Do i need to import any files?

Comment: Refer to the [paramiko library](http://www.paramiko.org/)

Comment: If you explicitly want to use it with putty, you'll have to pass command line arguments to it, for which you can use the `subprocess` library.

Comment: Though, Ashisk is right, use paramiko or other native Python SSH library.